# wcf client performance investigation

Tags: performance, wcf

I know that Performance Counters exists for a WCF service.
I want to do some performance investigation on a generated WCF client.
I have set up the same diagnostics as Idid for the server but this does not seem to work. 
Is there a way to see the performance of a WCF client (response times etc) without writing custom code?

Thanks

Comment: You can use `perfon`, read more here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/431917/WCF-Service-Performance-Monitoring-using-Perfmon

Comment: Performance counters for the client are needed

Answer (score 0):

The following article - [Monitoring Client-Outbound WCF Calls](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rickrain/2012/01/27/monitoring-client-outbound-wcf-calls/) goes over how to accomplish this. It ties together the following events:

[ClientOperationCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee845503.aspx) and [Analytic Tracing with ETW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee530019.aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately this returns only the completed events and not the response times.